# Wanting to search for "multiple correlation" in my dataset. Do two or more variables together predict my target variable

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis, correlation

By Multiple Correlation I refer to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correlation

If I understand it right, this should give me the correlation of any two `x_1, x_2` together and how they correlate to a target variable `y`. At least that is what I am searching for. Any other approaches would be helpful too. How do I check if there is a correlation of not one variable to my target, but of two or more together.

This is not implemented by: [dataframe.corr()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)

Should I rather go by using **Linear Regression** or some simple **ML model**? It is important for me to see which variables are how strong in my model so to reconstruct this as a formula.

Answer (score 1):

As the wikipedia page you pointed says, the Multiple correlation measure is the correlation between the value predicted by a linear regression and the input data. If you want to do any prediction you will have to compute the linear regression.

`dataframe.corr` you mentioned, will give the `Rxx` matrix mentioned by wikipedia article. You still have to compute `c`, to plug in the equations.

Linear regression is the best way to go, it gives you a predictor that minimizes the error, and the error you can use to decide whether you consider that a good fit.